# Inline validation using Laravel Validator

Tags: laravel

Currently I can validate my form in the backend using `validator.`

What I'm trying to do is to validate the form per specific text input only.

Like for example.

I have `First name, Last name, Email, Username, Password and Confirm Password`

If I fill up all of these fields and only entered 3 char for password.

Validator will prompt a message below the text field of password saying

`The password must be at least 8 characters.`

Currently I can validate it, But I'm trying to figure out to place it below the text field

Here's my HTML

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('insertUser') }}">
    @csrf

    <!-- First Name -->
    <div class="md-form">
        <input type="text" id="materialLoginFormFName" class="form-control @error('fname') is-invalid @enderror" name="fname" required>
        <label for="materialLoginFormFName">{{ __('First Name') }}</label>

        @error('fname')
            <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
            </span>
        @enderror
    </div>

    <!-- Last Name -->
    <div class="md-form">
        <input type="text" id="materialLoginFormLName" class="form-control @error('lname') is-invalid @enderror" name="lname" required>
        <label for="materialLoginFormLName">{{ __('Last Name') }}</label>

        @error('lname')
            <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
            </span>
        @enderror
    </div>

    <!-- Username -->
    <div class="md-form">
        <input type="text" id="materialLoginFormUName" class="form-control @error('uname') is-invalid @enderror" name="uname" required>
        <label for="materialLoginFormUName">{{ __('Username') }}</label>

        @error('uname')
            <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
            </span>
        @enderror
    </div>

    <!-- Email Address -->
    <div class="md-form">
        <input type="email" id="materialLoginFormEmail" class="form-control @error('email') is-invalid @enderror" name="email" required>
        <label for="materialLoginFormEmail">{{ __('E-Mail Address') }}</label>

        @error('email')
            <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
            </span>
        @enderror
    </div>


    <!-- Password -->
    <div class="md-form">
        <input type="password" id="materialLoginFormPass" class="form-control @error('password') is-invalid @enderror" name="password" required>
        <label for="materialLoginFormPass">{{ __('Password') }}</label>

        @error('password')
            <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
            </span>
        @enderror
    </div>

    <!-- Password -->
    <div class="md-form">
        <input id="password-confirm" type="password" class="form-control" name="password_confirmation" required autocomplete="new-password">
        <label for="password-confirm">{{ __('Confirm Password') }}</label>
    </div>

  </div>

    <button type="submit" name="submitNewUser" class="btn btn-success waves-effect" id="submitNewUser">{{ __('Save') }}</button>
    </form>
```

Here's my controller

```
public function insertUser(Request $request)
{
    $data = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'fname' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
        'lname' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
        'uname' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
        'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
        'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8', 'confirmed'],
    ]);

    if ($data->fails()) {
        return $data->errors()->all();
    } else {
        return back()->with('success','Successfully Registered!');
    }
}
```

Here's a sample illustration of output I'm trying to do

[image]

Comment: so what is your problem? What does not work?

Comment: Replace `return $data->errors()->all();` with `return back()->withErrors($data->errors()->all());`